# Compare two observable values and return result in an array - Angular Rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to compare two observable method and return the result. I tried an example but didn't get the expected result.
I hope the following example (what I tried) make the question more clear.

```
GetCountries() : Observable<any>
{
  return this.http.GetCountries().subscribe(data => {
    return  data;
  })
}

GetSelectedCities() : Observable<any>
  {
    return this.http.GetCities().map(data => {
      return   data
    });

  }

let cities = [{name:'new york', id:1},
    {name:'paris', id:2},
    {name:'london', id:3}]

    let countries = [{name:'usa', id:1, city:'new york'},
    {name:'germany', id:2,city:'berlin'},
    {name:'france', id:3,city:'marseille'},
    {name:'netherland', id:3,city:'amersterdam'}]

GetNotSelectedCities()
{
  this.GetCountries.do(data => {
    this.GetSelectedCities.do(response => {
      data.filter(x=> return response.filter(d=> d.city !== x.name ) )
    })
  })
}
```

But I'm getting list of cities instead of this result:

```
[{name:'germany', id:2,city:'berlin'},
    {name:'france', id:3,city:'paris'},
    {name:'netherland', id:3,city:'amersterdam'}]
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a return statement in your `GetNotSelectedCities` function

Comment: That's correct you are searching countries and getting all the counties records except that city, tell here what would be your expected result???

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GetNotSelectedCities() {
   forkJoin([
      this.GetCountries(),
      this.GetSelectedCities(),
   ])
   .pipe(
       map(([countries, cities]) => {
          return countries.filter(country => !cities.find(c => c.name === country.city));
       })
   )
   .subscribe(notSelected => {
      console.log(notSelected);
   });
}
```

Comment: Just to complement: since Rxjs 6.5, `forkJoin` can take an `object` as parameter, like this: `forkJoin({ countries: this.GetCountries(), cities: this.GetSelectedCities() })`.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively:

```
GetCountries() : Observable<any>
{
  return this.http.GetCountries();
}

GetSelectedCities() : Observable<any>
  {
    return this.http.GetCities();

  }

let cities = [{name:'new york', id:1},
    {name:'paris', id:2},
    {name:'london', id:3}]

    let countries = [{name:'usa', id:1, city:'new york'},
    {name:'germany', id:2,city:'berlin'},
    {name:'france', id:3,city:'marseille'},
    {name:'netherland', id:3,city:'amersterdam'}]

GetNotSelectedCities()
{
   return combineLatest([this.GetCountries(), this.GetSelectedCities()]).pipe(map([countries, cities]) => {
    return countries.filter(country => cities.filter(d=> d.city !== country.name ).length > 0 );
}))
}
```

This however will require you to subscribe to this wherever you want to use this combinelatest.

Comment: I wish people could comment as to why they found the answer bad. Mostly to understand why and learn from it

Comment: Not sure why ppl downvoted, but I noticed some issues with your answer: 1 - it doesn't even compile (you forgot the argument in cities' `filter`). 2 - a boolean value should be returned in the second `filter`, otherwise the condition gonna be ALWAYS true, because the `filter` method ALWAYS return an `array` (even if no elements match a condition - in this case, an empty array is returned). So, yes, `filter` isn't the most appropriate way to do this (you can try with `some` method). 3 - IHMO `combineLatest` isn't the most appropriate operator for this (maybe `forkJoin` or `zip` suits better).

Comment: And it seems that OP is using an old version of RXJS (no pipeable operators yet)... so it may not work as he/she expected.

Comment: Thanks. I remedied 1, sort of fixed 2, although the find method is better. 3, I am not sure why that is the case (at this moment), so I need to read up on forkJoin and zip, although zip I have an idea what does.

Comment: Just a statement: `some` is the most appropriate method you can use for this, you don't care about the value, but the truthiness.